# General internet search engine showing only non-commerical sites?

Tags: open-source, web-apps, search-engine, hosted

Are there any general internet search engines that can limit hits to exclusively free non-commercial websites?  (No '[.com](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.com)'s or '[.biz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.biz)'s, no [paywall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paywall)s, no membership-based revenue models, etc.)

So, for example, a search for "foobar" would show results from *Wikipedia*, *Project Gutenburg*, and '[.gov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.gov)' sites, but **not** from *Twitter*, *Facebook*, *Amazon*, etc. The results of a search should not include [SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) garbage.

Comment: I begin to develop [**Kristinita's Search**](http://kristinita.ru), largely like your requirements. See [**description of search engine**](http://cyclowiki.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA:%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0_%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B). But it's only for Russian-languages sites. Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, Thanks, just was testing it.  While I'd prefer something that's more linguistically general, *KS* is still quite useful under *Chromium* with auto-translate on.  Please repost your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

### 1. Briefly about Kristinita'S Search

I have long been worried about the problem, which raised in @agc question. Recently I begin to develop [**Kristinita's Search**](http://kristinita.netlify.com) — search engine, which searches for information only in [**open access**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_access) sources, written by professionals in the theme.

I do not find choice except to add each website, which will be searched, manually. In my search engine not paywalls, internet-magazines, social networks, SEO garbage and so on. I add **only sites, useful for science**.

---

### 2. Limits

1. I'm sorry, the project not ready yet. Please, do not hit me hard.
2. Kristinita's search only for [**Runet**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_in_Russian). I understand, that more be better to create search engine that include English and more languages, but I can not to do a huge amount of work.

About others limits and shortcomings see in [**this section**](http://cyclowiki.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA:%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0_%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B#.D0.9D.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.BA.D0.B8_.D0.9F.D0.BE.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B0_.D0.9A.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.82.D1.8B).

---

### 3. Examples

#### 1. The construction term:

- *Google*: 7 sites to sell products, 1 forum thread, images and 1 science article.

[image: Google construction 1]

[image: Google construction 2]

- *Kristinita's Search*: 10 science articles.

[image: Kris construction 1]

[image: Kris construction 2]

Kristinita's Search not include commercial, non-science sites.

#### 2. The chemical term

- [**CyberLeninka**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) — 2 articles about [**BeO**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beryllium_oxide) (only about toxical properties) and 9 casual mentions in the text.

[image: Cyber BeO 1]

[image: Cyber BeO 2]

[image: Cyber BeO 3]

[image: Cyber BeO 4]

- *Kristinita's Search* — 9 chemical articles about BeO, 1 casual mention.

[image: Kris BeO 1]

[image: Kris BeO 2]

Kristinita's Search was included more materials and have more relevance search result than CyberLeninka, Google Scholar, Google Academy, eLIBRARY and others science search engine in Russian language.

#### 3. Aquarium fish

- *Yandex*: 9 amateur sites, images and Wikipedia.

[image: Yandex Gurami 1]

[image: Yandex Gurami 2]

- *Kristinita's Search*: 10 articles in professional journals for the aquarists.

[image: Kris Gurami 1]

[image: Kris Gurami 2]

Kristinita's Search included only materials written by professionals, not amateurs.

#### 4. President of Russian Federation

- *Yandex*: Official site, Wikipedia, 2 news feed, 3 profiles in social networks, 2 sites of non-professional authors, 2 mass media sites

[image: Yandex Putin 1]

[image: Yandex Putin 2]

- *Kristinita's Search*: 6 biographies in mass-media, 3 biographies in wiki-sites, 1 biography of person bearing the same surname.

[image: Kris Putin 1]

[image: Kris Putin 2]

Kristinita's Search is encyclopedia and not included news and social networks.

---

### 4. Additional links

Materials from links in Russian language.

- [**Detailed description of Kristinita's Search**](http://cyclowiki.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA:%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0_%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B);
- [**More examples**](http://cyclowiki.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA:%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0_%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B);
- [**About sites inclusion criteria in Kristinita's Search**](http://cyclowiki.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA:%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0_%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B#.D0.93.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B4.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.9A.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.82.D1.8B).

If you want to make similar search system, you may write me according to [**any of the contacts**](http://uid.me/sasha_chernykh) — I try to help you. Also, I will not refuse, if someone offer me any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a [Mycroft](http://mycroftproject.com/) search engine plugin for [Kristinita's Search](http://mycroftproject.com/search-engines.html?name=kristinita).

Comment: @agc, I add [**opensearch.xml**](http://www.opensearch.org/Home) for Kristinita's Search, I planned to add Kristinita's Search in Mycroft, also, in [**Bang**](https://duckduckgo.com/bang?), [**Qwant**](https://www.qwant.com/qwick) and so on. But first I must at least to work at design of Kristinita's Search documentation :) . But thank you very much!

Comment: Update: unfortunately a check on 5/23/19 shows that *Kristinita's Search* currently links to some sort of pornography site.

Comment: @agc, can you add more details about «check, shows that Kristinita's Search currently links to some sort of pornography site»? How reproduce this check? Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help, if at all possible.  Clicking on `https://kristinita.ru/` goes to a "*Gif Porn Tube*" page.  The bottom of the page has the text: "*DMCA 2257 Contact Us  
© Copyright 2019 kristinita.ru - All rights reserved.*"

Comment: @agc, thanks for message! [**geoscreenshot.com**](https://www.geoscreenshot.com/) show, that [**porn on kristinita.ru domain**](https://i.imgur.com/tmZkr5t.png). My domain registrar increased the price 10 times → didn't give me a chance register domain again in another place. [**Someone else owns this domain**](http://whois.domaintools.com/kristinita.ru). Apparently, this is some kind of criminal scheme.

Comment: My website at the time on [**Netlify**](https://www.netlify.com/) → address is [**https://kristinita.netlify.com**](https://kristinita.netlify.com). It open source, code [**on GitHub**](https://github.com/Kristinita/KristinitaPelican). Thanks.

Comment: Using the new *Nelify* address, I've updated the [Mycroft plugin for Kristinita's Search](https://mycroftproject.com/search-engines.html?name=kristinita.netlify.com).

Answer (score 2):

Searx's Science only search will search 10 or so engines dedicated only to science! This will leave out Wikipedia though. It is a metasearch engine. Find instances here. https://asciimoo.github.io/searx/user/public_instances.html https://stats.searx.xyz/